# Scanner nextLine() not waiting for input on loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The following code takes an input of 1, 2, or 3 from `System.in` and acts accordingly, looping trials until the number "3 (or an invalid `String`)" is entered, and the program exits. I need to use `nextLine()` instead of `nextInt()` so that inputs like "123" or "123abc" all fall into the last "else" and cause the program to exit.
The program works fine the first time, but on the second iteration, the console outputs `Trial 2:` and then I get a `NoSuchElementException: No line found`. View the stack trace below.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int trialNumber = 1;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Trial " + trialNumber + ": ");
        input = s.nextLine();
        int type = determineInputType(input); //Parses input and returns 1 2 or 3

        if (type == 1) {
            // ...
        }
        else if (type == 2) {
            // ...
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Exiting!"); 
            break;
        }
        trialNumber++;
    }
    s.close();

}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at edu.iastate.cs228.hw4.InfixPostfix.main(InfixPostfix.java:39)
```

Thanks for the assistance!

EDIT: Below is the source for determineInputType(input)

```
    private static int determineInputType(String input) {

    switch (input) {
    case "1":
        return 1;
    case "2":
        return 2;
    case "3":
        return 3;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid option.");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the determineInputType method declared.

Comment: Please post the code for `determineInputType`

Comment: What are the `// ...`? Is there code that you omitted? (If so, we probably need to see it.)

Comment: Radiodef you are right. Something inside my `if (type == 1)` breaks it. When I comment out everything the code works as expected. I should be able to find the error. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: A lesson here: you will want to do debugging first to isolate the error before asking questions on it. Else you risk posting code that is irrelevant to the problem. Glad you've got it solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely you are creating a new `Scanner` in the `determineInputType` method, or somewhere in your `// ...`.

When you close a `Scanner`, the `InputStream` that it uses gets closed too. So if you open a `Scanner` for `System.in` and then close it, every other opened `Scanner` won't be able to read from `System.in` anymore.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    // [...]
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String myString = s.nextLine();
    determineInputType(myString);
    // [...]
    s.close();
}

public static void determineInputType(String str) {
    // [...]
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    // [...]

    /* This will affect the 's' Scanner from the 'main' method too
     * as it closes System.in, which is being used from 's' too
     */
    s1.close(); 

}
```

Comment: You are correct. It is not in `determineInputType`, but I do create another scanner inside my actions for `if (type ==1)`. I will have to find another way around. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @zZShort_CircuitZz You don't have to find another way. Just use the same `Scanner` for all the application :)

Comment: Right, I did just that and it works beautifully. It took me a minute to realize the original scanner doesn't care about what was previously input.

Comment: @BackSlash how do you reopen the System.in if you close it?

Comment: @CodeCamper I don't know if there is a direct way, but generally opening a new scanner should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing this code

This line is the possible problem causer. I directly set the of the input to 1 (`int type = 1;` instead of that method). , Then it worked as expected.

```
    public class Snippet {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            int trialNumber = 1;

            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = null;
            while (true) {
      System.out.print("Trial " + trialNumber + ": ");
                 input = s.nextLine();


                int type = determineInputType(input);

                if (type == 1) {
                    // ...
                }
                else if (type == 2) {
                    // ...
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("Exiting!"); 
                    break;
                }
                trialNumber++;
            }
            s.close();

    }
        private static int determineInputType(String input) {

            switch (input) {
            case "1":
                return 1;
            case "2":
                return 2;
            case "3":
                return 3;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option.");
                return 0;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, what is it about determineInputType() that messes up the Scanner then?

Comment: Share the code written for determineInputType(String) method, i can even provide better solution

Answer (score 0):

You need just one more line in your code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int trialNumber = 1;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = null;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Trial " + trialNumber + ": ");
            s.nextLine();
            input = s.nextLine();
            int type = determineInputType(input); //Parses input and returns 1 2 or 3

            if (type == 1) {
                // ...
            }
            else if (type == 2) {
                // ...
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Exiting!"); 
                break;
            }
            trialNumber++;
        }
        s.close();

    }
```